# Why do some companies explicitly assign a very low cash value to promotions?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, corporate-law, disclaimers

I came across this small print for the [opening days promotion](https://timhortons.co.uk/openingdayoffers) on the Tim Hortons UK website:

[image]

Specifically, both offers contain the following disclaimers in the small print:

> Cash value £0.0001p. Not transferrable for cash.

What's the purpose of explicitly giving a promotion a minutely small cash value rather than just doing what most companies do and saying it has no cash value at all? Is there any benefit to doing so?

Answer (score 3):

It's for the damages you'd get if this card would be made invalid by TH deciding not to honor the deal anymore. It's not "the price of 730 cups of coffee" but the value of a peppercorn.